# Why can I not change $\mathrm{dv}\mathrm{du}$ to $\mathrm{du}\mathrm{dv}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-forms

Say I want to integrate a nice enough function $f: \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ over a region $R \subset\mathbb{R^2},$ hence evaluating

$$
\int_R f(x,y) \;\mathrm{dxdy}.
$$

But since this is too hard, I perform the integration in coordinates $(u, v)$ different to $(x, y).$ Say the region $R$ in $(u,v)$ is $R'.$

Using $x = x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$, I obtain
$$
\mathrm{dx} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \mathrm{du}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\mathrm{dv}
\quad\quad
\mathrm{dy}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \mathrm{du} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \mathrm{dv}.
$$
So I thought I just 'multiply' them (using distributive property) to get
$$
\mathrm{dxdy} = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \mathrm{du}+ \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\mathrm{dv}\right) \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \mathrm{du} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \mathrm{dv}\right) =
\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\mathrm{du}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \mathrm{du}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\mathrm{dv}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \mathrm{du}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\mathrm{du}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \mathrm{dv}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\mathrm{dv}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \mathrm{dv}.
$$
I know I want something proportional to $\mathrm{dudv}$ so I ignore the $\mathrm{du}\mathrm{du}$ and $\mathrm{dv}\mathrm{dv}$ terms, this leaves

$$
\mathrm{dxdy} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\mathrm{dv}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \mathrm{du}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\mathrm{du}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \mathrm{dv}
$$
Given the context in which these differentials were motivated to me and the fact I know the solution to this integration problem, I went ahead and assumed (kind of) linearity so factor out the partial derivatives, such
$$
\mathrm{dxdy} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\mathrm{dv} \mathrm{du}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\mathrm{du} \mathrm{dv}.
$$
Now I'm stuck. I know I need $\mathrm{dvdu} = -\mathrm{dudv}.$ But why does that not work? I'm so close to the determinant of the Jacobian. Why can't I just say

$$
\int_R f(x,y) \;\mathrm{dxdy} = \int_{R'} f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\;\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\mathrm{dv} \mathrm{du}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\mathrm{du} \mathrm{dv}\right)=
\\
\int_{R'} f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\;\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\mathrm{dv} \mathrm{du}+\int_{R'} f(x(u,v),y(u,v))\;
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\mathrm{du} \mathrm{dv}.
$$
Finally use Fubini to integrate what ever I want first. - It's as if differentials have a direction.

Comment: If $dudu=0$, then $d(u+v)d(u+v) = dudu + dvdu + dudv + dvdv =0$. Then $dvdu+dudv=0$. So that $dvdu=-dudv$.

Comment: $du dv$ is "alike" a cross product $du \times dv$ because it represents the **oriented** (hence "signed") area of an infinitesimal parallelogram. Therefore, as a cross product it is antisymmetric : $dv \times du = -du \times dv$. In fact, it would be better to represent $dudv$ as an "exterior product" $du \wedge dv$... but that would take pages to explain it...

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/903808/305862)